# How to ReWriteRule and then Redirect 301 it using .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rid off .php and create a SEO friendly url. here is the scenario:

examplesite.com/platform/sign-in.php should be displayed / accessible in examplesite.com/platform/login/

the following rule makes that happen. now I can visit to the `examplesite.com/platform/sign-in.php` just by visiting to `examplesite.com/platform/login/`

```
RewriteRule    ^platform/login/?$    platform/sign-in.php [NC,L]
```

`examplesite.com/platform/login/` is my login page now but this page `examplesite.com/platform/sign-in.php` stays same. I can visit to `examplesite.com/platform/sign-in.php` as well.
So I tried this redirection to redirect the users to `examplesite.com/platform/login/`if they visit to `examplesite.com/platform/sign-in.php`

```
Redirect 301    /platform/sign-in.php /platform/login/
```

Now when I visit to `examplesite.com/platform/sign-in.php` it says **too many redirections** and loads nothing.

how to solve this?
`examplesite.com/platform/sign-in.php` should be auto redirect to `examplesite.com/platform/login/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^platform/login/?$ /platform/sign-in.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/platform/sign-in.php
RewriteRule ^platform/sign-in.php /platform/login/ [NC,R=301,L]
```